# How to initialize a LiveData in a ViewModel without Transformations.map?

Tags: android, viewmodel, transformation, android-livedata

In my Android project, I have a ViewModel class that performs a search in a Movie repository:

```
class MoviesViewModel(private val repository: TmdbRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val queryLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val moviesResult: LiveData<MovieSearchResult> = Transformations.map(queryLiveData) {
        repository.search(it) // The return type of this method is MovieSearchResult
    }

    val movies: LiveData<PagedList<Movie>> = Transformations.switchMap(moviesResult) { it.data }

    /**
     * Search movies based on a query string.
     */
    fun searchMovies(queryString: String) {
        Log.i(AppConfiguration.TAG, "SearchMoviesViewModel.searchMovies().")
        queryLiveData.postValue(queryString)
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the class `MovieSearchResult`:

```
data class MovieSearchResult(
    val data: LiveData<List<Movie>>
)
```

The method `repository.search(it)` of `MoviesViewModel` accesses a Dao model that returns the following method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE title LIKE '%' || :search || '%'")
fun getMoviesByName(search: String?): LiveData<List<Movie>>
```

In `MoviesViewModel`, the type of the variable `moviesResult` is `LiveData<MovieSearchResult>`, and the type of `repository.search(it)` is `MovieSearchResult`.

So, we are transforming the type `MovieSearchResult` to `LiveData<MovieSearchResult>` through the method `Transformations.map()`. Okay.

The search above uses a `queryLiveData`, that is `MutableLiveData<String>`.

So here is my question: how should I initialize a new `LiveData` attribute if I need to implement a search that doesn't need a parameter? If I need to create a `LiveData` that will access a Dao method like below...

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Movie")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Movie>>
```

... how should I define my `LiveData` attribute?

For instance: the following method won't not compile:

`private val allMoviesResult: LiveData<MovieSearchResult> = repository.getAll(it)`

But that's what I need to do: enter with `repository.getAll(it)` and get a `LiveData<MovieSearchResult>`.

Comment: Well why are you passing an `it` to a parameter that does not need an argument?

Comment: To make it work!
It is not the most elegant way, but it work.
What is the most elegant way? Well, that's what I am seeking in this post.

Comment: But it doesn't work if you are passing a parameter to a function that doesn't accept arguments, which is why I was asking.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is going to work or if there are better solutions, but maybe you can try something like this:

```
class MoviesViewModel(private val repository: TmdbRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val queryInput = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val moviesResult: LiveData<MovieSearchResult> = Transformations.switchMap(queryInput) { query ->
        if (query == "ALL") {
            repository.all()
        } else { 
            repository.search(query)
        }
    }

    // I am also not sure about handle a List<Movie> as a PagedList<Movie> 
    val movies: LiveData<PagedList<Movie>> = Transformations.switchMap(moviesResult) { it.data }

    fun searchMovies(queryString: String) {
        queryInput.value = queryString
    }

    fun getAllMovies() {
        queryLiveData.value = "ALL"
    }
}
```